What is the etymology of ゴミ
When I first heard ゴミ I thought it was written with Kanji but it was actually written with Katakana which probably means that it's a loanword. What is its origin? Asking this here because Jisho.org didn't explain it, thanks.

Nobody knows for certain. Wiktionary describes at least 5 theories. And katakana is also used for native words, especially names of biological species, since kanji for them are often outside jōyō kanji list and are not taught in schools in Japan.

@Arfrever Seems like answer material to me.

Apparently the Kanji for it is 芥
